# Canvas - dynamic drawing and managing shapes

Tags: silverlight, canvas

I'm trying to make an application which allows the user to draw shapes to the canvas. Once drawn, I would like for the user to be able to select, move, resize, basically manipulate the shapes in any which way.

I have done something similar in XNA and that was quite easy due to the fact that there was a draw loop. In Silverlight there is no such thing as far as I understand and I am having trouble figuring out how to manage the objects on the canvas. As in what is the best way to manage the canvas' children collection to ensure appropriate response of the UI to what the user does.

Most examples out there are pretty basic and do not go anywhere near this kind of thing. I would be grateful if somebody who has done this before could tell me how they approached the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about it for a while I think I figured out how it works.

There is a draw loop for the canvas, which is the draw loop of the top level parent container which it lives on.
The difference with XNA I guess is that the collection of items to draw on the canvas doesn't need to be explicitly drawn, since the canvas takes care of drawing its children automatically.

So, what I need is some way to hold on to any object I add to the canvas' children... I can then update the objects drawing properties and the changes will be reflected in the canvas next time it refreshes.

I guess a dictionary of some sort in which to store the items I put in the list might be best...?

Not a finished answer yet, but I guess I understand half of it now.

Comment: You may benefit from this series of articles: http://cgeers.com/2010/04/18/silverlight-asteroids-part-1-game-loop/. One of the first things the author does is set up a canvas with render loop and sprite list etc.

Comment: That was extremely interesting. Thanks!